# How do I properly stream media from my torrent box *without* transcoding?

Tags: windows-7, linux, video-streaming, utorrent

I have a torrentbox. The special thing about this torrent box is that it's custom built, it has Windows 7 installed and I have full control over it using TightVNC.

At the moment I'm using uTorrent WebUI and FTP do download the files. But I'm thinking - When I download a 1,5 hour long video in 30 minutes, wouldn't it be theoretically possible to just WATCH the movie directly from the torrentbox? Obviously this can't be done using FTP since it makes you download the entire file, BUT:

Is there some other way to fool your OS into thinking that this is a local folder, and get media players like VLC or GOM player to play video files directly? This would be a monumental time- and space saver for me.

(I have both Windows and Linux Mint on my PCs)

Comment: You can't just use VLC to stream it from the box?

Comment: Voting to move to superuser.com -- From the ServerFault faq: Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity.

Comment: How is this even slightly professional sysadmin related?

Comment: @Chopper3 Who are you referring to? I created this question on the site that seemed the most server related, as my question concerns a connection between servers

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @codemonkey - well you can't have read or understood the SF FAQ then.

Answer (score 1):

I would just map a shared folder as a network drive. No fancy streaming solutions needed.

It may be worth noting that torrents don't download from beginning to end, so it's entirely possible that a very early piece of the movie would get downloaded after 25 minutes.

Although I don't have any experience with Linux Mint specifically, I know that both Debian and Ubuntu can [mount a shared (SMB) folder](http://wiki.debian.org/Manual-Howto#MountWindowsShare) locally [without too much hassle](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently). Since Linux Mint is derived off of those distributions, I would assume it can too.

[image: Click "map network drive"]
[image: Configure the network drive]

Comment: Mapping network drives assumes that the torrentbox is on my network. My torrentbox is a windows PC somewhere else in the world, and my main PC is a Linux Mint box. I really have no clue how to connect these two boxes without FTP

Comment: I see. You didn't mention that in [the original question](http://superuser.com/revisions/dad5794d-aec7-4421-bdbb-4a0aa9f09f64). Perhaps you could edit it in. I guess it depends on the bandwidth between you and the box. What happens if you browse the FTP site in Explorer and simply double click the file? Nautilus offers similar functionality. @Codemonkey

Comment: This can't be done with FTP. If you `GET` a file using FTP the whole file gets downloaded before it opens. I know that the bandwidth between my boxes is sufficient to watch videos from start to end directly from my torrentbox, but I know of no actual way of doing this. I suppose there is third-party software out there that will accomplish what I'm after, which is why I'm asking around :-)

Comment: Fair enough. Will let you know if I think of anything. @Codemonkey

Comment: It appears Windows Media Player has internet streaming functionality [built in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/05/12/media-streaming-with-windows-7.aspx), but I assume it _does_ transcode. @Codemonkey

Comment: Indeed. The perfect solution would be to fool Windows/Linux to thinking the mapped drive is a local drive, since the bandwidth is more than capable of running files directly from the torrentbox. I am currently searching for 3rd party software that would be capable of this. Meanwhile I'm hoping that someone from superuser.com knows how it's done :-)

Comment: Perhaps something like [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/features.aspx) might do the trick... @Codemonkey